# Erro ao Importar Package GoLang

Tags: golang, packages

Estou tentando chamar uma função de outro package no `main` mas quando importo e tento usar a função exportada retorna o erro de `"package functions imported but not used"`.

### function.go

(go/src/github.com/dashadelas/teste/functions/function.go)

```
package functions

import (
    "fmt"
)

func GetFunction() {
     fmt.Println("teste")
}
```

### main.go

(go/src/github.com/dashadelas/teste/main.go)

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/dashadelas/teste/functions"
)

func main() {
    GetFunction()
}
```

Alguém sabe me dizer a origem deste erro? Eu executei o `go mod init`, `go mod tydi` e o `go mod vendor` também!

Answer (score 0):

Você fez a importação do package, mas não colocou o nome do mesmo antes da função `GetFunction`, para corrigir, escreva o nome do package antes de utilizar da função, exemplo:

```
functions.GetFunction()
```

---

Além disso, pode ser necessário fazer o `go get`, configurar o `GOPATH` etc.

---

Criei exatamente o se exemplo no github para exemplicar na prática:
https://github.com/Dadinel/so497165

Comment: Acho que o $GOPATH está tranquilo, pois quando executo "CD $GOPATH" ele abre a pasta do Go!